# asyncio.create_task does not run async method in background

Tags: python, python-asyncio

hey hi in python fastapi i have these methods:

```
semaphore_update_mview_rasa_family_list = asyncio.Semaphore(1)


def update_materialized_view(id_=str(uuid.uuid4())):
    log_file_and_shelve(id_=id_, message="update_materialized_view started updating mview")
    session, engine = get_db_session()
    session.execute(text("CALL dbms_mview.refresh(:mview)"), params={"mview": 'MVIEW_RASA_FAMILY_LIST'})
    session.close()
    q = last_mat_view_update_time()
    log_file_and_shelve(id_=id_, message=f"update_materialized_view finished updating mview {q}")
    return q


def last_mat_view_update_time():
    session, engine = get_db_session()
    q = session.execute(text("""
    SELECT to_char(LAST_REFRESH_DATE, 'yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss', 'nls_calendar=persian') j_LAST_REFRESH_DATE, 
    to_char(LAST_REFRESH_END_TIME, 'yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss', 'nls_calendar=persian') j_LAST_REFRESH_END_TIME,
    LAST_REFRESH_DATE, LAST_REFRESH_END_TIME
    FROM USER_MVIEWS
    WHERE MVIEW_NAME = 'MVIEW_RASA_FAMILY_LIST'
    """)).fetchone()
    session.close()
    return list(q)



async def _semaphore_update_mview_rasa_family_list(id_=str(uuid.uuid4())):
    async with semaphore_update_mview_rasa_family_list:
        update_materialized_view(id_=id_)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


@app.get("/update-mat-view", tags=['Database Service', 'Update Database'])
async def update_mview_rasa_family_list():
    id_ = str(uuid.uuid4())
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(_semaphore_update_mview_rasa_family_list(id_=id_))
    return {"transaction_id": id_}
```

when i call my url. it suppose to run my `_semaphore_update_mview_rasa_family_list` in background and return transaction code immediately. but it awaits until my method runs completely then returns transaction code

Comment: Are you saying that one second elapses between the create_task call and the return statement?  I don't see how that's possible.  Have you tried inserting print statements into _update_mview_rasa_family_list to print out time stamps?

Comment: you right. I tested that already. it seems behavior of fastapi is the reason of waiting

Comment: I'm still skeptical.  AFAIK loop.create_task only schedules a task, it doesn't run it.  Execution of a new task shouldn't begin until the current task hits an await expression.  Therefore I don't see how fastAPI can suspend `update_mview_rasa_family_list`.  Have you tried separating out the call to the coroutine `_semaphore_update_mview_rasa_family_list()` from the call to `loop.create_task`?  Something is just not making sense here.

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code.

```html
@app.get("/update-mat-view", tags=['Database Service', 'Update Database'])
async def update_mview_rasa_family_list():
    id_ = str(uuid.uuid4())
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(_semaphore_update_mview_rasa_family_list,id_)
    return {"transaction_id": id_}
```

Comment: no `TypeError: BaseEventLoop.create_task() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given` i tried `    functools.partial` it does not work tho

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).